# Conversion of Alphabets into numbers

Tags: java, android, android-source

I am beginner in programming , I have converted numbers into alphabets in C# Now i want to convert that Alphabets back to those numbers in Android .Thanks in advance.Code which i used for C#:

```
string a = textBox1.Text;
string temp = "LMNAOTUTRYEN";
string ans = "";
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
ans += temp[a[i] - 48];
textBox2.Text = ans;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = textBox1.getText().toString();
String temp = "LMNAOTUTRYEN";
String ans = "";
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
ans += temp.charAt(a.charAt(i) - 48);
textBox2.setText(ans);
```

But use StringBuilder better:

```
String a = textBox1.getText().toString();
String temp = "LMNAOTUTRYEN";
StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
ans.append(temp.charAt(a.charAt(i) - 48));
textBox2.setText(ans.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// get text from EditText
String a = editText1.getText().toString();
// convert it to number
String temp = "LMNAOTUTRYEN";
String ans = "";
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    ans += temp.indexOf(a.charAt(i));
}
// show the number
textView1.setText(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify that you want to get ASCII value or numeric value. I have done it according ASCII value.Here is the code.

```
 String temp = "LMNAOTUTRYEN";
 StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        int j = temp.charAt(i); 
        ans.append(String.valueOf(j));
    }
```

The output is 767778657984858482896978.